# XAML TreeView Expand Vertically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I would like the TreeView below to expand to fill the current row that it is contained within, however, I can't figure out how this is done. It just expands to fit the tree items.  Can this be done, and if so, how?

Thanks

```
<Window x:Class="WorkoutUI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Name="Window" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="Root_Grid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" Name="Root_Grid_Row_2" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />            
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TreeView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=Root_Grid, Mode=Default}">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Workouts" IsExpanded="True">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Workout1" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Workout2" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Workout3" IsExpanded="True">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="WorkoutSub1" />
                    <TreeViewItem Header="WorkoutSub2" />
                    <TreeViewItem Header="WorkoutSub3" />
                </TreeViewItem>    
                <TreeViewItem Header="Workout4" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Workout5" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Workout6" />                
            </TreeViewItem>            
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `VerticalAlignment="Top"`, which means the TreeView will only be as tall as it wants to be and will be placed in the top of the available space.  You want to set the [VerticalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.verticalalignment.aspx) to Stretch so that it will take up all available vertical space.  Since this is the default, you can just remove the attribute:

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=Root_Grid, Mode=Default}">
```